# onLeaveStep of Smart-Wizard doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, smart-wizard

I am trying to call onLeaveStep from the smart wizard like so

```
...
onLeaveStep: leaveStep
...
```

Other than that all the parameters of the wizard are as instructed here http://techlaboratory.net/smartwizard/documentation#paramdesc

The problem is that when I add this line of code, i cannot click the NEXT button. For now the function leaveStep looks like

```
leaveStep = function(from, to) {
   //do nothing

}
```

Thanks in advanced.
David

Answer (score 3):

you have to return true in order to advance to the next step

```
leaveStep = function(from, to) {
    //do nothing

    return true;
}
```